How to convert pydantic model to python dataclass?
There the opposite is very popular question. Why not to convert a ready pydantic model into a standard python library dataclass?

There is a solution idea. It hasn't been tested widely yet, so I'll glad to receive comments with concerns and fixes.
from pydantic import BaseModel
from pydantic_core import PydanticUndefined
import dataclasses

def pydantic_to_dataclass(
    klass: Type[BaseModel],
    classname: str = None,
) -> Any:
"""
Dataclass from Pydantic model

Transferred entities:
    * Field names
    * Type annotations, except of Annotated etc
    * Default factory or default value

Validators are not transferred.

Order of fields may change due to dataclass's positional arguments.

"""
dataclass_args = []
for name, info in klass.model_fields.items():
    if info.default_factory is not None:
        dataclass_field = dataclasses.field(
            default_factory=info.default_factory,
        )
        dataclass_arg = (name, info.annotation, dataclass_field)
    elif info.default is not PydanticUndefined:
        dataclass_field = dataclasses.field(
            default=info.get_default(),
        )
        dataclass_arg = (name, info.annotation, dataclass_field)
    else:
        dataclass_arg = (name, info.annotation)
    dataclass_args.append(dataclass_arg)
dataclass_args.sort(key=lambda arg: len(arg) > 2)
return dataclasses.make_dataclass(
    classname or f'__{klass.__name__}Dataclass',
    dataclass_args,
)

Test case.
    from typing import List, Mapping, Annotated
    import uuid
    from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

    def test__pydantic_to_dataclass():
        def _default_factory():
            return str(uuid.uuid4())

        class ModelForTest(BaseModel):
            a: int
            b: str = Field(..., alias='alias_b', max_length=5)
            c: str = 'ccc'
            d: List[Mapping]
            e: bool = None
            f: Annotated[str, Field(default_factory=_default_factory)]

        model_for_test = ModelForTest(a=13, alias_b='bbb', d=[{}])
        assert isinstance(model_for_test, BaseModel)

        dc_cls = pydantic_to_dataclass(ModelForTest)
        assert dc_cls.__annotations__ == {
            'a': int,
            'b': str,
            'c': str,
            'd': List[Mapping],
            'e': bool,
            'f': str,
        }
        dc_instance = dc_cls(
            13,
            'bbb',
            [{}],  # order has been changed, here is d
        )
        assert dc_instance.c == 'ccc'
        assert dc_instance.d == [{}]
        assert len(dc_instance.f) == len(str(uuid.uuid4()))
        assert dc_instance.e is None

